# Why can I omit the space after -m when executing python scripts at the command line?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

If I make a file like

```
# test.py

print('Hello World')
```

and I run

```
python -m test
```

then the python script runs.
But if I run

```
python -mtest
```

the program ALSO runs.

I would expect omitting that space causes some kind of error. Is this expected behavior? Is this typical behavior when running commands at the command line?

Comment: This is standard Unix command-line syntax. The space between an option and its parameter is optional. It's not specific to python.

Comment: @Barmar That comment sounds like the answer to my question. If you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Given the answer, I don't think this is really a question about Python.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel in light of the answer, yes, but when writing the question I didn't know the answer would be generic to Unix command line arguments. Happy to add or remove tags as people think fit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common convention for Unix command line arguments. It follows from the [CLI argument conventions of POSIX utilities](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_01):

> If the SYNOPSIS of a standard utility shows an option with a mandatory option-argument (as with `[ -c option_argument]` in the example), a conforming application shall **use separate arguments for that option and its option-argument**. However, a conforming implementation shall also permit applications to **specify the option and option-argument in the same argument string without intervening  characters.**

This syntax is particularly common for flags like `-W`, where you'll almost always see `-W error` shortened to `-Werror`.

To emphasize the this is the expected convention, note that Python's `argparse` supports the same syntax:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-m")

>>> parser.parse_args(["-mtest"])
Namespace(m='test')
```

See also these related questions from Unix & Linux SE:

- [Why can spaces between options and parameters be omitted?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/292232/564341)
- [Why did "argument can be squished against option" prevail over "argument is always separate"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/188046/564341)

Answer (score 1):

This is normal Unix command-line syntax. When an option takes a parameter, the parameter can be immediately after the option or it can be the next argument.